# cross validating time series model

Tags: time-series, cross-validation, standard-deviation, heatmap

I'm evaluating a model predicting clickrate. I have series of clicks and impressions.
At the moment I'm evaluating a particular feature `X`. It's a categorical variable, and it has 11 different values.
I have 8 months of data, and I compute clickrate for each month for each value of `X`. Here is corresponding heatmap:
[image]
each column corresponds to a particular `X`. It's prominent that the clickrate is consistently higher for some `X`, so I'm going to use this feature in my predictor.
Now, I have several several questions:

- is it a good idea to evaluate this model this way? I know there is also a correlation between adjacent values in time series, so should I consider only using each second month? Or split the data in some other way (e.g. by user's id last digit)?
- How to quantify this "consistency"? I have a hypothesis that some `X` values are better predictors than others, which values should I compare? I considered standard deviation (of clickrate values for a given `X` value among all the months), would that be a reasonable choice? Then I could only include a subset of `X` values in my model (i.e. the ones with `std < Δ`)
- Related to the previous point: I have two ways of inferring `X` feature itself. Would it be reasonable to compare this "consistency" among `X` values, inferred different ways? Then I would be able to say that one is better and use it.

Comment: What is the actual model here?

Comment: Well, in general it's an ensemble recommender system, but here we can assume that I just predict clickrate by the `X` value. So, `crt(x) = clicks(x) / impressions(x)` where `ctr(x)` is predicted clickrate  for a particular `x` value of `X`